# execute a drop down function on a vertical navigation using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I can't figure out how to execute a drop down function on a vertical navigation using Jquery. In the HTML I have a nav section declared and 1st level list items with nest li's creating second level menu items.

When the 1st level li is clicked, I want the nested ul to toggle *SHOW/HIDE* the nested ul/li's of that specific parent `li`.

**HTML:**

```
<aside class="sidebar clearfix">

    <nav id="mnCat" class="primary clearfix">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="selected" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".braids">Braids</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Corn Rows</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Micro Braids</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Single Braids</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".twists">Twists</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Curly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kinky</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Straight</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wavy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".weaving">Weaving</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Straight</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Wet & Wavy</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Curly</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Deep Wave</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Kinky</a></li>
                    </ul>                       
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".wigs">Wigs</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Half Wigs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Full Wigs</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Lace Fronts</a></li>
                    </ul>                    
                </li>
                <li><a href="#" data-filter=".silk">Silk Fantasy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

</aside>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 

    var $dropDown = $('nav#mnCat ul li ul');
            $dropDown.addClass("drop");

    var $trig = $('nav#mnCat ul');
            $trigger = $trig.find('a'),         
            $trigger.click(function () {
                $dropD = $dropDown.find(this),

                $dropD.css("display","block");


                });

    });
```

jSfiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/SDYXy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean something like this?:

```
$trigger.click(function () {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
}
```

Here is the fiddle with the above implementation . http://jsfiddle.net/hearsid/SDYXy/1/

Comment: @SiddharthSharma I have rolled back your edit because the link pointed to the same fiddle as the original answer. Feel free to add the correct link if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would handle this is by assigning a matching `class` and `id` to the `<li>` and their child `<ul>` tags. Then, use a combination of `.slideToggle()`, `.slideUp()` and `.not()` to make everything behave as expected. Something like this should do the trick:

HTML

```
    <nav id="mnCat" class="primary clearfix">
        <ul class="parent">
            <li><a href="#" class="selected" data-filter="*">All</a></li>
            <li class="braids"><a href="#" data-filter=".braids">Braids</a>
                <ul id="braids">
                    <li><a href="#">Corn Rows</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Micro Braids</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Single Braids</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="twists"><a href="#" data-filter=".twists">Twists</a>
                <ul id="twists">
                    <li><a href="#">Curly</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kinky</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Straight</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wavy</a></li>
                </ul>
            <li class="weaving"><a href="#" data-filter=".weaving">Weaving</a>
                <ul id="weaving">
                    <li><a href="#">Straight</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Wet & Wavy</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Curly</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Deep Wave</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Kinky</a></li>
                </ul>                       
            </li>
            <li class="wigs"><a href="#" data-filter=".wigs">Wigs</a>
                <ul id="wigs">
                    <li><a href="#">Half Wigs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Full Wigs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Lace Fronts</a></li>
                </ul>                    
            </li>
            <li class="silk"><a href="#" data-filter=".silk">Silk Fantasy</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('.parent li').click(function () {
        var showMe = $(this).attr('class');
        $('ul#'+showMe).slideToggle();
        $('.parent ul').not('#'+showMe).slideUp();
    });
});
```

And finally add this bit of CSS

```
.parent ul {
    display: none;
}
```

This ensures that when you click on a section, that section's contents slide down into view, and all other section's contents will slide up from view. It also allows you to click on a currently visible section in order to hide it.

And here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/2GwJ5/1/